# Как проверить находится элемент в видимости экрана?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Сейчас есть список товаров который подгружается по нажатию кнопки (добавить + 20 товаров).

Не могу понять по какому событию мне нужно перехватить появление этой кнопки в зоне видимости экрана?

Answer (score 1):

Можно scroll, или timeOut; в обоих случаях:

1. запомнить позицию этой кнопки;
2. проверять смещение прокрутки по вертикали;
3. после очередной подгрузки данных выполнить 1).

Answer (score 0):

Легко вот так:

```
var $init = $('.item-class');
if ($init.length) {
    $init.bind('inview', function(event, isInView) {
          var $this = $(this);
          if (isInView) {
              $this.addClass('in-viewport');
          } else {
              $this.removeClass('in-viewport');
          }
    }
}
```

Но для этого нужно подключить: https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview/blob/master/jquery.inview.min.js

Всего 1.2Kb